# Best way to send a bunch of emails without user input on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, smtp

First, let me get this out of the way and say this isn't a spam application. I'm writing an app that allows users to share files with multiple friends easily via email.

Right now, I'm using  [`SKPSMTPMessage`](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) to send out emails to a list of recipients at the user's request. It works, but I wonder if there isn't a better solution here. For example, if it might be better to send the `smtp` info and attachments to my server, and conduct the sending from there in order to avoid repetitive attachment uploads on the device.

I am also considering how to handle cases where there is no connection available (determining connection error vs other kinds of errors and persisting the failed message for a later retry).

Any advice on the best way to structure this service would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you send only one email, with every recipient in the `Bcc` field (instead of the `To` field, so they don't see each other in the list or recipients when they receive the email), to avoid the phone sending the attachments multiple times and only send them once to the server?

Comment: Good idea. I admit, I'm not very knowledgable about the way email works, so that didn't occur to me. I guess all that's left, then, is to manage the sending and possible failures, particularly if the app enters the background.

Comment: Well in that case, isn't it acceptable for your app to display a pre-filled email form (`MFMailComposeViewController` configured with the `Bcc` field, the title and the message body already filled) so that the user only have to hit the "Send" button? This is only one button to tap for the user (and still let him/her change the pre-filled message if s/he wants to), and you have the advantage that the OS take care of everything then, including sending the email in the background (especially useful if you have large attachments), managing failures (and retries) or unreachable network, and so on…

Comment: Nope, that form is slow, ugly, and would break the user experience. The reason I'm using SMTP is to avoid it in favor of something faster and less invasive.

Answer (score 0):

In order to customize the user experience for sending e-mail you need access to their email details, IMAP, POP, etc. if you want that user to be the one sending the e-mail.

The solution I use is to have the from address be an e-mail I control and use a 3rd party email provider, ex: SendGrid, PostMark, Mandrill and plug in to their api's to send e-mails.